# Couchdb - How get results in reversed order by date and without id field

Tags: couchdb

I'm testing some Couchdb features and I want get results with a reversed order by insertion date, querying by "i" field
A sample doc:

```
{
   "_id": "970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091a4d2b",
   "_rev": "1-54448147611ff5e89189bb44e58c1521",
   "doc_type": "Test",
   "e": "3/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/36/2",
   "d": "64/183/329/2/360/10/13/47/6/351/331/320/355/342/7/335/47/18/30/56/18/323/351/325/323/218/163/155/155/155/155",
   "f": "1399305161/1399305185/1399305194/1399305254/1399305314/1399305374/1399305434/1399305447/1399305506/1399305566/1399305626/1399305668/1399305727/1399305787/1399305847/1399305908/1399305963/1399305970/1399306022/1399306068/1399306078/1399306100/1399306159/1399306219/1399306279/1399306308/1399306321/1399306379/1399306439/1399306493/1399306506",
   "i": "3566120224",
   "dated": "1399305161",
   "v": "0/5/6/32/63/63/51/16/35/60/0/10/64/31/64/48/14/31/6/55/60/50/0/0/21/5/34/0/0/0/0",
   "date": "2014-05-05T15:52:42Z"
}
```

My view:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.i && doc.date){
      emit([doc.i,doc.date],1); // 1 to test only
  }
}
```

I'm testing it with:

```
myview?startkey=["3566120224"]&endkey=["3566120224",{}]&reversed=true
```

But I'm getting the data with a date order not reversed

```
{"total_rows":545,"offset":508,"rows":[
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da906515e","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:11:01Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da9062b51","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:15:21Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da905f4d9","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:19:41Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da905b4e1","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:24:01Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da905733c","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:28:22Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da904e7ea","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:32:42Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da9043709","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:37:02Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da9039896","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:41:22Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da90303be","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:45:43Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da90239ae","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:50:03Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da9018442","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:54:23Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da90104f0","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T14:58:43Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"407ee687674b783601ce6d7da9007b67","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:03:04Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"90bb394f7a4a581ff4dc78bfaffff448","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:07:24Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"90bb394f7a4a581ff4dc78bfafff368e","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:11:44Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"90bb394f7a4a581ff4dc78bfaffe7e65","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:16:05Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091f8e5c","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:24:45Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091f6241","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:29:05Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091f254a","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:33:26Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091ed01b","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:37:46Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091e5f42","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:42:06Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091dd992","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:46:26Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091d3853","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:50:47Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091c9a3c","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:55:07Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091bf465","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T15:59:27Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091ba442","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:03:47Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091ad482","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:08:08Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb4075091a2130","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:12:28Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb40750919a6ef","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:16:48Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb407509192479","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:21:08Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb40750918a977","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:25:29Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb40750917b468","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:29:49Z"],"value":1},
{"id":"970c3a0fdbb23dde47fb407509170583","key":["3566120224","2014-05-05T16:34:09Z"],"value":1}
]}
```

I have two times the same data(date & dated[ms date]), 1399305161 that is = 2014-05-05T15:52:42Z
thinking that I could order the results with a data type more easy to parse for couchdb, but didn't work using the dated field
Also I don't need the id field, how can exclude it from the results?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options), you can see that `reverse` is not a supported query option. To reverse the data, you want to do:

```
myview?endkey=["3566120224"]&startkey=["3566120224",{}]&descending=false
```

If you don't want the ID field, you can just return the reduced value at the highest grouping level:

```
myview?endkey=["3566120224"]&startkey=["3566120224",{}]&descending=false&group_level=2
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the doc.i just write:

```
    function(doc) {
      if(doc.i && doc.date){
        emit([doc.date],1); // just removed doc.i
     }
    }
```

To reverse the results:

- You can either change the results so that you use the descending option. I'd think that is bad practice though as it depends on the client using this feature.
- Assuming it's the default use of the view, I'd opt to returning the date as integer. `Date.parse(doc.date).valueof()` should do the trick of returning the epoch time as integer or double. If you then return this with a '-' (minus) the view will by default be sorted in descending order. This is assuming you don't need the formatted date in the key.